# Using Bootstrap's progress bar as a count down timer

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, momentjs

I am using bootstrap's progress bar in order to display a live time counter. The idea behind this is simply to show how many hours and minutes you have been working on a project.

So far what I got working is the live counter that updates every minute. If youve been working on this project for more than 6 hours it turns yellow and red after 8 hours.

What I haven't been able to figure out is how do I get it the progress bar to progressively increase to 100%? For example, it should reach 100% once it reaches to 8 hours.

Heres an example of what I was able to accomplish so far.
https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/18405/

```
var update = function () {
  $.each($(".timer_cell"), function () {
    var start_time = $(this).closest('tr').find('.start_time').html();
    var live_timer_div = $(this).find(".live_timer_div");

    function updateDuration(startTime, endTime) {
      var ms = moment(endTime, 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm').diff(moment(startTime, 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm')),
      dt = moment.duration(ms),
      h = Math.floor(dt.asHours()),
      m = moment.utc(ms).format('mm');
      live_timer_div.html(h + ' hours, ' + m + ' minutes');

      if (h >= 8) {
      live_timer_div.removeClass("progress-bar-success progress-bar-warning");
      live_timer_div.addClass("progress-bar-danger");
      }
      else if (h >= 6){
      live_timer_div.removeClass("progress-bar-success progress-bar-danger");
      live_timer_div.addClass("progress-bar-warning");
      }

    };

    updateDuration(start_time, moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm'));  
  });
};

$(document).ready(function(){
update();
setInterval(update, 61000);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var progressBarPercentage = (h * 60 + Number(m)) * percentageIncrement;` Determines the percentage to set for each `progressbar`. `percentageIncrement` is `100/480 (0.208%)`, which represents the percentage amount to increase every minute.

Finally, `live_timer_div.css("width", progressBarPercentage + "%");` sets the required `width` for each `progressbar`.

**[Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/yassarikhan786/DTcHh/18406/)**

```
var percentageIncrement = 100 / 480; //480 minutes in 8 hours. 100 / 480 = the amount to increase the percentage bar per minute
var progressBarPercentage;

var update = function() {
    console.log("UPDATE");
  $.each($(".timer_cell"), function() {
    var start_time = $(this).closest('tr').find('.start_time').html();
    var live_timer_div = $(this).find(".live_timer_div");

    function updateDuration(startTime, endTime) {
      var ms = moment(endTime, 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm').diff(moment(startTime, 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm')),
        dt = moment.duration(ms),
        h = Math.floor(dt.asHours()),
        m = moment.utc(ms).format('mm');
      live_timer_div.html(h + ' hours, ' + m + ' minutes');

      progressBarPercentage = (h * 60 + Number(m)) * percentageIncrement;

      live_timer_div.css("width", progressBarPercentage + "%");

      if (h >= 8) {
        live_timer_div.removeClass("progress-bar-success progress-bar-warning");
        live_timer_div.addClass("progress-bar-danger");
      } else if (h >= 6) {
        live_timer_div.removeClass("progress-bar-success progress-bar-danger");
        live_timer_div.addClass("progress-bar-warning");
      }

    };

    updateDuration(start_time, moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm'));
  });
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  update();
  setInterval(update, 61000);
});
```

Comment: You're welcome. freedomn-m's suggestion to set the percentage to 100 if the value is greater than 100 would improve the code further.

Answer (score 1):

Add this:

```
  var max = 8*60*60*1000;
  var pos = ms/max * 100;
  if (pos > 100) pos = 100;
  live_timer_div.css("width", pos + "%")
```

Because the size of the progress is based on %age, you need a simple calc to convert actual compared with max to %age.

In your fiddle, most of them are over 100%, so I've added a check for this, but in reality you might like a stacked bar with 3 parts green/yellow/red with green at 8 hours at 50% of the bar, showing where >8hrs quite clearly

Or you can simply change the 8(hours) to eg 16(hours) in the code above, but might be confusing.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/18407/